# How can I prove this $\int_{\gamma}f=-\int_{-\gamma}f$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 64 he made the following definition:

> **Definition.** Let $\sigma:[c,d]\to \mathbb C$ and $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ be rectifiable paths. The path $\sigma$ is equivalent to
>   $\gamma$ if there is a function $f:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ which is
>   continuous, strictly increasing, and with $f(c)=a,\ f(d)=b$; such that
>   $\sigma=\gamma\circ f$.

This is a equivalence relation and after this he introduce another definition:

> **Definition.** If $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve for $a\le t\le b$, then denote by $-\gamma$ the curve defined by$(-\gamma)(t)=\gamma(-t)$ for $-b\le
>  t\le -a$.

So based on these definitions how can I prove this

$$\int_{\gamma}f=-\int_{-\gamma}f$$

This is an one line proof, I've already some demonstrations of this fact, but I always get confused with the choice of the parametrization. If someone could make this proof with details I would be very grateful.

Comment: Take the definition of $\int_{-\gamma} f$ and apply the change of variables theorem.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I don't know this theorem, do you know if Conway has mentioned this theorem in his book? thank you

Comment: @user42912 It's from freshman calculus. Use the definition and then you have a Riemann integral. Then use the "change of variables theorem" otherwise known as u substitution.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo could you please make an answer with the details please? my problem is with the details of this proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(t_0 =a,t_1,...,t_n = b)$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Then
$(-t_n ,...,-t_0)$ is a partition of $[-b,-a]$.

Assuming $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.
Suppose $\epsilon>0$, then  we
may assume that the mesh size is small enough so that
$|f(t_k) - f(t_{k-1})| < \epsilon$ for all $k$.

Note that $(-\gamma)(t) = \gamma(-t)$. To avoid confusion $-\gamma$ with
negation, let $\eta = -\gamma$, then $\eta(-t) = \gamma(t)$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k f(\gamma(t_k)) (\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})) &=& \sum_k f(\eta(-t_k)) (\eta(-t_k) - \eta(-t_{k-1})) \\
&=& -\sum_k f(\eta(-t_k)) ( \eta(-t_{k-1}) - \eta(-t_k)) \\
&=& -\sum_k f(\eta(-t_{k-1})) ( \eta(-t_{k-1}) - \eta(-t_k)) + \sum_k (f(\eta(-t_{k-1}))- f(\eta(-t_{k}))) ( \eta(-t_{k-1}) - \eta(-t_k))
\end{eqnarray}
and so we have
$|\sum_k f(\gamma(t_k)) (\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})) - (-\sum_k f(\eta(-t_{k-1})) ( \eta(-t_{k-1}) - \eta(-t_k)))| < \epsilon(b-a)$.

Now take limits as the mesh size of the partition goes to zero and we get
$|\int_\gamma f dz - (-\int_{-\gamma} f dz)| \le \epsilon(b-a)$.
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I'll do the job for path integrals. You can visualize complex integrals as particular cases of this (for instance, the real part and imaginary part can be separated and be seen as path integrals of $(f_1,-f_2)$ and $(f_2,f_1)$), or simply adapt the arguments. In any case, I'll leave the job of transitioning the result for you. If you have difficulties, tell me.

I'll change his notation of $-\gamma$ to $\Gamma$, and call the function $x \mapsto -x$ as $g$. Note that $\Gamma'=-\gamma ' \circ g$. We have that

$$\int_{\Gamma} f=\int_{-b}^{-a} f\circ \Gamma \cdot \Gamma'=\int_{-b}^{-a} f \circ (\gamma \circ g) \cdot (-\gamma ' \circ g)$$
$$=\int_{-b}^{-a} \big((f \circ \gamma) \circ g \big) \cdot (-\gamma' \circ g)$$
$$=\int_{g(-b)}^{g(-a)}(f \circ \gamma ) \cdot (-\gamma')\cdot (-1)=\int_{b}^{a}(f \circ \gamma) \cdot \gamma'=-\int_a^b (f \circ \gamma) \cdot \gamma'=-\int_{\gamma} f.$$

Comment: Why is the first equality true? Thank you

Comment: @user42912 The first equality is true by definition of the path integral. The second equality is true by the observation I made (which is true by the chain rule), the third equality is true by associativity of composition, the fourth by change of variables (note that $-1$ is the derivative of $g$), the fourth is simply simplifying things, the fifth is interchanging the limits of integration and the sixth is due to the definition of path integral again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't understand very well your answer. I will try to understand it again tomorrow, thank you again.